# Capturar Vídeo e Áudio

Tags: java

Estou montando um programa que interage com o usuário, e quero implementar no mesmo captura de áudio e vídeo, porém a única maneira que encontrei foi com API..
Existe alguma maneira de se fazer uma captura de vídeo(webcam) e áudio de um usuário sem o uso de API em Java?

se não, qual seria a API mais apropriada?

Answer (score 2):

Não! não há um meio de fazer o que desejas sem uso de uma API mais apropriada. A linguagem Java não fornece meios para accessar o hardware.